# Can't pull a Gradle project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, plugins, gradle, pull

I'm part of a team working on a game project and we just moved our project to using Gradle. I can pull, commit, merge and push normally with Git GUI in Windows Explorer, but other members of the team can also pull in Eclipse by right-clicking the Gradle-project folder in Project Explorer view, choosing Team-menu and then Pull. However, in my Eclipse the "Team" settings only give me options to "Apply Patch" and "Share Project.." the whole team has tried to find a solution for this to no avail so far.

Before the project was built on Gradle, I was also able to pull in Eclipse by using the aforementioned method. We're using Git repository.

Any suggestions on where to look for the cause of this malfunction?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume then you don't store the Eclipse project files/settings in your Git repository but create them locally using `gradle eclipse`.

Then after importing the project into Eclipse (be sure not to copy it to the workspace) you can use the *Share project...* option under *Team* in the context menu. Then choose *Git*. Eclipse EGit will automatically detect if your project resides in an existing repository (it should be listed on the next wizard page) and set up the corresponding association.

The term *Share project* maybe is a bit confusing, as you also do it for projects that already are under version control.